# Social Notes from other users disappearing on some page loads

Tags: social, social-note

For random page loads social notes from other people dissapears. The persons own notes are shown. In some cases this happens every two pageloads, when doing testing by constant refreshes of the page. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Social tags are referenced by URL on a item level, i also had this issue but it worked after switching to a FQDN url. Does this error occur differently with an admin or regular user?

Comment: We are using fqdn url. Looks like it is the same behaviour for both admin and regular. The count of Tags And Notes are correct though. I am thinking it might be related to security trimming and search as of this article http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff608006.aspx